# Как в postgresql найти все значения по неполному ключу jsonb?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Не получается написать запрос в postgresql для поиска всех ключей которые имеют одинаковое окончание в jsonb-колонке.
например у меня есть структура в которой есть ключи с "%_id":
{
"type": "1",
"type_id": "2",
"subtype": "3",
"subtype_id": "4",
"new_id": "5",
}
нужно отобрать записи в которых есть значения с "%_id"

Comment: Получите массив имён атрибутов (json_object_keys function), отберите нужные, по ним получите массив значений.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE).

```
with
  j(jb) as (
    values
      ('{ "type": "1", "type_id": "2", "subtype": "3", "subtype_id": "4", "new_id": "5" }'::jsonb)
  )
select
  key, value
from
  j,
  jsonb_each(j.jb) as jbe
where
  key like '%\_id' escape '\'
;
```

Результат:

```
+------------+-------+
|    key     | value |
+------------+-------+
| new_id     | "5"   |
| type_id    | "2"   |
| subtype_id | "4"   |
+------------+-------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/113644).